# Setting TTL doesn't remove the records in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I use Robo Mongo to run my Mongo DB queries. I have a collection which has '`requestReceivedTimestamp`' column that holds date time (Example: 12/13/2016 23:18:56 EST). I have used the below commands to setup the TTL Expiry index on this column. For some reason, i don't see the records getting removed. Am i doing something wrong here?

`db.logging.createIndex( { "requestReceivedTimestamp": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 2592000 } )`  --> Ran this command to create a TTL index on `'requestReceivedTimestamp'`

To Enable the MongoDB TTL Monitoring: `db.adminCommand({setParameter:1, ttlMonitorEnabled:true});` --> This command to make sure the `ttlMonitor` is ON. I don't know how to see, if it is **ON** or **OFF**, so i had run this command to turn it ON.

This is how data looks like using mongo DB.

[How the collection looks like in RoboMongo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCCe5.png)

Answer (score 2):

The value of `requestReceivedTimestamp` should be an ISO Date (maybe a timestamp): https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

To create an ISO Date:

```
new Date()
new Date('July 22, 2013 14:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Paul Rey. After inserting the column data using new Date(), i was able to the delete the rows after indexing the new column with ttl expiry date. Used the same command - `db.logging.createIndex( { "recordCreateDate": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 2592000 } )`

[Image of the inserted record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goZWs.png)